# Issue with multiple quotation marks

Tags: xcode, swift

I can't figure out how I am supposed to write this. Can anyone help?

```
"do shell script \"osascript -e 'quit app "\(clientUsed)"'""
```

The script is supposed to say this (if notes was clientUsed)

```
osascript -e 'quit app "notes"'
```

Comment: If I see it correctly, this is an AppleScript which uses "do shell script …" to execute another AppleScript via "osascript" ? Looks a bit complicated … Is there any reason not to call `"quit app \"\(clientUsed)\""` directly ?

Comment: Does that quit the app using a force quit or using a safe quit?

Comment: Oh this seems to work! :) Is this a safe method of quitting an app?

Comment: I have no idea. Your question was about *how to call* certain AppleScript commands, not what these commands do. – (But when I try it with an editor with unsaved changes, then a dialog comes up asking if I want to save them.)

Comment: Okay thanks. Know a better way to call `let openCommand = "do shell script \"open -j -g -a /Applications/\(clientUsed).app\""` ?

Comment: Is this the same question or a different question? You already accepted an answer for this one, and marked your previous question as "SOLVED". – And actually I would use NSTask instead of AppleScript (as was already suggested to you).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77105/discussion-between-dantdd-and-martin-r).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with this (we escape `"` with `\"` )

```
"do shell script \"osascript -e 'quit app \"\(clientUsed)\"'\""
```

it corresponds to the command:

```
do shell script "osascript -e 'quit app "YOUR_CLIENT_USED"'"
```

Comment: "do shell script \"osascript -e 'quit app \"\(clientUsed)\"'" doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: see the updated content, I've missed a \ . The rule is use \ to escape `"`, and to use `\(some_variable)` to include some variable's content

Comment: Hmm still trying to run it and it's not executing the command properly :(

Comment: Have you tried to execute this shell cmd in the console? To sure that it works well.

Comment: Or maybe you don't have permission to run this from your app?

Comment: When I execute osascript -e 'quit app "notes"' in terminal, it works. But when I try and run this script in Xcode it's not executing.

Comment: It's not sudo so it doesn't require any extra permissions right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77101/discussion-between-hoaparis-and-dantdd).